# How to install the dynamic content compression component of IIS (both 6 and 7) non interactively?

Tags: iis, compression

Any of the following goes as non interactive for me:

- Command line silent installation
- Script file
- Code (.NET, C, VB, whatever)

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'd like to stress, that I wish to install the module responsible for the dynamic content compression. This is different from configuring the dynamic content compression after the respective module has already been installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIS7.x

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx

```
C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Appcmd.exe set config -section:urlCompression -doStaticCompression:true -doDynamicCompression:true
C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Appcmd.exe set config -section:httpCompression -[name='gzip'].staticCompressionLevel:9 -[name='gzip'].dynamicCompressionLevel:4
```

IIS 6

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/12/IIS-Compression-in-IIS6.0.aspx

```
cscript C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/site#/root/DoStaticCompression False
cscript C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/site#/root/DoDynamicCompression False
```

Comment: Not quite. This stuff is only valid if the dynamic content compression module has already been installed, see http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression. I want to know how to install it non interactively, rather than configure after it is already there.

Comment: In IIS7 you can do it with the following command line command: "start /w pkgmgr /iu:HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic".  IIS6 does have it automatically so it's a non-issue there.